# How do I use h2o4gpu in kaggle kernel?

Tags: h2o, kaggle, h2o4gpu

I'm trying to setup h2o4gpu library to be used in Kaggle competition, but I haven't found any useful resource to install/setup the environment. How do I set it up step by step?

I have tried using the R package installation guide from this source : https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu

But I still cannot make it work. I'm using below code, it installs the h2o4gpu package for R but I still receive error.

```
if (!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("h2oai/h2o4gpu", subdir = "src/interface_r")
```

I'm hoping a simple step by step guide. Thank you.

Comment: can you also provide the error message you got the official directions are here https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu/blob/master/README.md within the repo you pointed to. Please also provide some details about your R environment.

Comment: Hi @Lauren thank you for your reply. Please find my installation here : https://www.kaggle.com/deint007/installing-h2o4gpu?scriptVersionId=9469498

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The h2o4gpu package for R requires the h2o4gpu python package to be installed as well. From the [docs](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu#h2o4gpu-R-package):

> At this point, you should have installed the H2O4GPU Python package successfully.

The error you are experiencing looks like it matches the description of a missing python package, described under "Python issues" here: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu/tree/master/src/interface_r

If you want to use h2o4gpu from within a Kaggle kernel, I'm not sure if this is possible, since Kaggle currently disables external packages when using a GPU.

Comment: Pretty sad it didn't support in kaggle. Thank you for your help!